# Declaring all elements of an associative array in a single statement - AWK

Tags: awk, associative-array, gawk

I am fairly new to `awk` and am trying to figure out how to declare all elements of an associative array in one go. For example, if I wanted to declare an associative array in Python (which is effectively the dictionary) I would do this:

```
numbers = {'uno': 1, 'sero': 0}
```

Now, in `awk` is it possible to convert the two lines of code below into one?

```
 numbers["uno"] = 1
 numbers["sero"] = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWK doesn't have array literals as far as I know, but this script demonstrates something you can do to get close:

```
BEGIN {
    split("uno|1|sero|0",a,"|");
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i += 2) {b[a[i]] = a[i+1];}
}
END {
    print b["sero"];
    print b["uno"];
}
```

Of course, you can always make a function that could be called like

```
newarray("uno", 1, "sero", 0);
```

or like

```
newarray("uno|1|sero|0");
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Best you can do is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    # populate the "numbers" array:
    split("uno:1,sero:0",a,/[:,]/)

    for (i=1;i in a;i+=2)
        numbers[a[i]] = a[i+1]

    # print the "numbers" array:
    for (i in numbers)
        print i, numbers[i]
}'
uno 1
sero 0
```